# PHP - MySql : How to store values from [input text] and [dropdown value] in db

Tags: php

I have 4 tables in mySQL db :

1. “product” table (product_id, other fields) - stores products' list
2. “product-detail” table (detail_id, other fields) - stores details' list
3. “product_ product-detail” table (product_id, detail_id, detail_value) – each product has many different details, so they are stored in this separate table; detail_value can be any type of data: text, numeric, date/time, boolean
4. “option” table (option_id, other fields) – options for details’ dropdowns in the form

In my product inserting form, I have two types of fields for providing product’s details (text and select):

```
// product’s fields
…
…
// product_details’ fields
    <input type='text' name="details">

    <select name="details">
    <option value="12">option 1</option>
    <option value="145">option 2</option>
    <option value="3456">option 3</option>
    </select>
```

where option value is the id of the provided option (from table "option").

When the form is submitted: one record with product data is inserted in “product” table, then
details of product (2 records):

- text value (1-st record) – a string,
- option value (2-nd record) – a numeric value

are inserted in table “product_ product-detail”.

So my questions are:

1. Is it good idea to store different types of data – text and id of the option - in the field “detail_value” (table “product_ product-detail”)?
2. Is there a better solution to products’ details storage in db?

Comment: The general rule with DBs is to store your data in as normalised and concise a format as possible. Don't store text where storing IDs will do instead. Otherwise, if you store text, that text will be repeated across multiple rows, and if you ever want to change that text you have to do it in all those rows.

Comment: I deleted my answer below as your question is misleading. It seems you don't need help inserting data to MYSQL. Table advice? Avoid duplication of information where possible. I built an entire ecommerce site with 1000's of products which has one single table for those products containing all the permanent data related to the products. The system is much more manageable this way.

Comment: How many fields do you have in your “product” table to store all details of different kind of products?
In my case I have ~100 types of products, each type has ~10 DIFFERENT details – does it mean I need ~1000 fields in my “product” table?

Answer (score -1):

```
    **Controller**
    public function get($id = null)
    { 
            $country = DB::table('countries')->lists('country_name','country_id');
            if(intval($id)>0)
        {
            $customer = Customers::find($id);
        }
        else
        {
            $customer = new Customers();
        }   
        return View::make('customerinfo.customer')->with('country',$country)->with('customer',$customer);
        }
    }
 public function save($id = null)
    { 
        if(intval($id)>0)
        {
            $custom = Customers::find($id);
        }
        else
        {
            $custom = new Customers();
        }
            $custom->name       =Input::get('name');
            $custom->country_id =Input::get('country_id');
            $custom->save();
        return Redirect::to('customer/'.$id);
    }
**blade**
<div class="form-group">
  <strong>Country</strong>
  {{ Form::select('country_id', array(''=> '--Select--') +$country, (isset($customer->country_id)? $customer->country_id: 100), ["class"=>"form-control col", "id"=>"country"]) }}  
</div>

<div class="form-group">  
    <strong> Name</strong>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" minlength="2" value="{{ Input::old('name') != null ?Input::old('name') : $customer->name; }}"> 
</div>
```

Comment: A public function seems overly complicated for what he needs also there's no sanitizing of data.